# How to "start over" with Docker?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run Tomcat in a Docker container with limited success. After I tried various things, I wanted to "reset" without completely deleting everything. I did stop and remove the virtual machine from the Virtualbox console. I then tried docker-machine create and docker-machine restart. My question is, if things reach a state in which the application appears to be hanging, what is the best procedure for starting from scratch that does not involve, for example, actually rebuilding the Docker container?

EDIT: All I am now asking is, given that "docker version" returns Client information but when it reaches the Server information I get the "An error occurred trying to connect" message, is what now needs to be done? What is it not connecting to? I tried with apparent success "docker-machine restart" but got no further with "docker version" after that.

Comment: There are two different entity with Docker. Images, built from `Dockerfile`, and containers, that are _running_ instances of a specific image. You can run several different container from the same sole image. When you applied modifications and want to "restart" or "start over" just exit the running container and run again the same image you were running. Is this is what you are looking for I'll post an longer answer with command lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't delete the boot2docker VM itself (created by docker-machine)
If you want to reset, you might have to delete the container and image (quickly rebuilt with a `docker build`). But you can stay in the same docker-based boot2docker VM. No need for deletion.

Retrying a docker container session simply involve killing/removing the current container, and doing a new `docker run`.

Then, don't forget check what is not working: does a `docker ps -a` shows your container running? Can you access Tomcat from the boot2docker Linux host? From your actual OS host?
Based on that diagnostic and the exact content of your Dockerfile, you will be able to debug the issue.

---

The main issue might come from the fact docker command are executed from outside the VM.
That works only if the commands from `docker-machine env <machine-name>` are set.
See [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/):

```
For cmd.exe:

$ docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd dev
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\captain\.docker\machine\machines\dev
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=dev
# Run this command to configure your shell: copy and paste the above values into your command prompt.
```

(replace "`dev`" by the name of your docker machine here, probably "`default`")

But it is also perfectly fine to make all docker command from *within* the VM. No "env" to set.

Everything is on the VM (images, `Dockerfile` which can be on the Windows host as well, as long as it is under `C:\Users\<yourLogin>`, since that folder is automatically mounted as `/c/Users/<yourLogin>`)

Comment: The build of the container for running tomcat takes a long time so I would prefer not having to rebuild. When I do a docker version it hangs for a while but eventually tells me about the client but then I get an error occurred trying to connect message -- does this mean the service on windows is not running and if so, what does one do?

Comment: @Jeff no the build does not take a long time as it uses caches: all the instructions unchanged will be instantaneous. Only what you are changing in the Dockerfile will reset the cache and take some time.

Comment: @Jeff "When I do a docker version it hangs for a while but eventually tells me about the client but then I get an error occurred trying to connect message -- does this mean the service on windows is not running and if so, what does one do?" Make sure you have the right docker-machine version, the latest from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases: it just a simple executable. No setup, no installation.

Comment: I should point out that I did get the image to run and at one point "docker version" worked -- given that it only tells me about the client now, does this imply that something that should be running on Windows is no longer running but can be restarted?

Comment: @Jeff no: docker-machine takes care of everything. There is no "service" running on Windows: everything runs within the boot2docker VM.

Comment: I just tried a: docker-machine restart followed by a docker version. The restart seemed to work but the version command still says "an error occurred trying to connect" -- so what is it trying to connect to? A VM? Because the VM is running. I am not trying yet to run the container, just trying to get the version command to work.

Comment: Did you do a docker-machine ssh first?

Comment: No but I just did that -- now what?

Comment: @Jeff no that you are in the VM itself, try again the docker version.

Comment: Yes, once I ssh the Client and the Server are shown. But after I exit from VM, docker version only shows Client info and I get the same error message. I have tried docker-machine env default without the results changing.

Comment: @Jeff don't exit from the VM: do all your docker command from a VM ssh session

Comment: @Jeff I see you have never or rarely accepted answer to your questions in the past. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer or http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and review your past questions.

Comment: Okay. But is there a way to get back to the situation where I don't have to be in the VM? The Dockerfile is not on the VM, is it? docker images when run on the VM doesn't show any.

Comment: @Jeff I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: Yes. The key was setting the env on the machine. I had thought the command actually set things but instead it just shows you what to set and when I did it, stuff started to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff Great \o/ Don't forget to review your past questions. Voting and accepting answers is how Stack Overflow works.